# Como hacer un UNPIVOT de más de una columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que crear una vista en SQL Server haciendo un UNPIVOT de una tabla y no consigo hacerlo correctamente.
A partir de una tabla origen como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que conseguir que se muestre así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo tendría que ser la consulta SQL para conseguir esta vista a partir de la tabla original? Los colores es simplemente para saber como se tienen que distribuir los valores en la consulta resultado.

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diría que, contrario a lo que dice el título de tu pregunta, quieres hacer un *unpivot* de una única columna (el `Tramo`), y luego quieres dejar en una única columna el valor de varias columnas del origen, dependiendo de cuál *tramo* resulte tener cada fila del resultado.

Para lograrlo, puedes hacer el `unpivot` *normal*, incluyendo ambas columnas (`P1`, `P2`) en el resultado, para finalmente, valiéndote de una sentencia `case` formar la columna `P` con el valor que corresponda (`P1` o `P2`) según el `Tramo`.

Este es uno de aquellos casos dónde un poco de código vale más que mil palabras. Suponiendo que tu tabla origen se llama `base`, esta sentencia te da el resultado:

```
select   IDBarem
       , IDTipo
       , Tramo
       , Nota
       , case 
           when Tramo = '50-54' then P1
           when Tramo = '55-59' then P2
         end P
  from (select IDBarem, IDTipo, P1, P2, [50-54], [55-59]
          from base) p
       unpivot (Nota for Tramo in ([50-54], [55-59])) as unpvt
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente!
La verdad es que no entiendo muy bien  el funcionamiento pero es totalmente correcto.
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Dejo una versión alternativa que tiene algunas ventajas, como mayor flexibilidad y simplicidad (en mi opinión). Es utilizando el constructor de tablas usando `VALUES` y la instrucción `APPLY`.

Dejo el código para después explicarlo.

```
SELECT  t.IDBarem,
        t.IDTipo,
        u.Tramo,
        u.Nota,
        u.P
FROM #Tabla t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( '50-54', t.[50-54], t.P1),
                   ( '55-59', t.[55-59], t.P2))u(Tramo, Nota, P);
```

Si nunca has usado `APPLY`, es una instrucción similar a `JOIN` pero en el que se pueden usar funciones o subconsultas que hagan referencia a las tablas anteriores. `CROSS APPLY` es similar a `INNER JOIN` y `OUTER APPLY` es similar a `LEFT JOIN`.

En este caso, vamos a usar `VALUES` para que podamos tener una fila por cada grupo de columnas que necesitemos. El grupo está conformado por un valor fijo que identificará a cada grupo (tramo) y por las columnas que lo conforman (nota y P). Así, si existieran más columnas, solo habría que agregarlas a los grupos de `VALUES`.

Si te parece más sencillo de enteder, podemos usar la versión compatible con 2005 también.

```
SELECT  t.IDBarem,
        t.IDTipo,
        u.Tramo,
        u.Nota,
        u.P
FROM #Prueba t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT '50-54', t.[50-54], t.P1 UNION ALL
             SELECT '55-59', t.[55-59], t.P2 )u(Tramo, Nota, P);
```